# tables into BCNF

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I would love to know if this tables are in proper **Boyce-Codd normal form**. Basically there is a **corporation** that owns N **shops** and every shop has N **workers**.
Every **corporation** has its own address, every **shop** has its own address - where it is located and even every **worker** has its own address where it lives.
[image]

Could it be like this - especially the address table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the determinants to do this properly but I will make assumptions. Corporation is in BCNF because it has two attributes and both are candidate keys -- it's a special case. 
Shop : if name and phone are both candidate keys then it's BCNF. Workers: if [Last Name + First Name] is a candidate key then it's BCNF. Address: block is duplicated across rows so it's not even 1NF, therefore it can't be BCNF.

Comment: So, how should I design the Address table to be in BCFN? also, should I make an address table for each table that has to have an address or could I make only one and connect them as I did? Because when you actually want to insert a data into DB, you have to fill all the foreign keys to specify worker's address.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, you need to define the determinants to formally prove BCNF. Have you done that?